# JQuery Masonry images are not stacking correctly

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

So i have initiated a simple masonry version to display my images, however it's not quite flowing the way I had anticipated.

This is how I am initializing masonry with the imagesLoaded plugin.

```
var $container = $('.grid');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth:  '.grid-item'
    });
});
```

However, as you can see from the image below the image is displaying to the right and not the left.

Each `.grid-item` has a float or left on it to stack the items to the left. What would cause this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that left picture (with the tables and/or the house) one pixel in height larger than the other images?

Comment: I believe it is by 2 pixels, but is it not possible to make it stack on the left rather than to the right?

Comment: Does it have to be via the masonry plugin?

Comment: It does yes there are various portrait and landscape images this wasnt the best example to show that but i dont have this issue on any of those pages as they work out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `direction: ltr;` to container div after removing the `float:left;` from the images

Comment: explain your answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using floats and left with Masonry? From my experience with it that will likely cause layout issues and the whole purpose of the plugin is to handle the layout for you.

If you want to stack in perfect grid patterns you'll likely have to specify height and width exact values as even 1 pixel can cause masonry to stack to the right because that's what it's designed to do.

With specific sizes it's fine if your photos are the same aspect ratio but as you mentioned you have portrait and landscape (ultra wide?) photos. So a portrait photo you could have:

```
<div class="grid-item v2"></div>
.grid-item { height: 100px; }
.grid-item .v2 { height: 200px }
```

With a Gutter specified you may need to add the gutter value to the .v2 height to compensate.